# Binomial sum - generating functions

Tags: generating-functions

Find a closed form for $a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n(-1)^k$ using generating functions.

Comment: With that tone of question, it might help if you showed us what you have tried.

Comment: @akotronis: (+1) for the interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n 
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{n}{n-k}(n-k)^n \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} k^n \\
&=& \left.\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} (x D)^n x^k\right|_{x=1} \\
&=& \left.(x D)^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} x^k\right|_{x=1} \\
&=& \left.(x D)^n (x-1)^n\right|_{x=1},
\end{eqnarray*}$$
where $D = \partial/\partial x$.
But 
$$(x D)^n = x^n D^n + (\mathrm{const}) x^{n-1}D^{n-1} + \ldots.$$
and $D^k(x-1)^n|_{x=1} = 0$ unless $k\ge n$. 
Therefore, 
$\left.(x D)^n (x-1)^n\right|_{x=1} = D^n(x-1)^n|_{x=1} = n!,$
and so 
$$\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n = n!.\tag{1}
\end{equation*}$$

---

<sub>The argument above immediately implies that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m = 0$$
if $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m<n$. 
It also gives us a method to calculate the sum for $m>n$. 
Sums of this type are related to the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m  
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}k^m  \\
&=& n! \left\{m\atop n\right\}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The operator $(x D)^n$ and it's connection to the Stirling numbers has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154887/nicer-expression-for-the-following-differential-operator/).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are trying to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (n-k)^n (-1)^k.$$

Observe that
$$(n-k)^n = 
\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \exp((n-k)z) \; dz.$$

This gives for the sum the integral
$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k \exp((n-k)z) \; dz
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\left(-1+\exp(z)\right)^n \; dz.$$

Now we have
$$[z^n] \left(-1+\exp(z)\right)^n = 1$$
by inspection, which then gives
$$n!$$
for the sum.